# could corosync can support unicast heartbeat mode?

Tags: corosync, linux-ha, unicast

could corosync can support unicast heartbeat mode?

from another thread in serverfault, some guy raised below corosync conf:

```
totem {
        version: 2
        secauth: off
        interface {
                member {
                        memberaddr: 10.xxx.xxx.xxx
                }
                member {
                        memberaddr: 10.xxx.xxx.xxx
                }
                ringnumber: 0
                bindnetaddr: 10.xxx.xxx.xxx
                mcastport: 694
        }
        transport: udpu
}
```

is this conf type means unicast mode?

thanks,
Emre

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's right. See also here, an example configuration published by Florian Haas (one of *the* Linux HA guys): https://github.com/fghaas/corosync/blob/master/conf/corosync.conf.example.udpu

And please read the Corosync man page, it's all explained in there.

Comment: i understand the multicast only can casted to next hop on network, is that right?  and corosync still use multicast to make heartbeat works, how does corosync achieve it on complicated/unexpected network topo environment?

Comment: You should really make yourself more familiar with the basics of components like Corosync and how they work (look into the redundant ring protocol, especially). But short answer: if your network topology is too complicated and unexpected then you can't reliably manage clustered resources over it. Simple as that.